# Query where search string completely contains indexed string

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In my index (using Elasticsearch 5.6.16) I would like to index words like "cat" or "funny dog". Now I would like to find only strings which are completely contained in my search query.

Example search queries should return

- "My favourite cat" -> ["cat"]
- "My funny cat" -> ["cat"]
- "My funny dog" -> ["funny dog"]
- "My dog is funny" -> []
- "My funny dogs" -> []
- "My cat and my funny dog" -> ["cat", "funny dog"]

Do you know which analyzers, tokenizers or filters to use for that purpose? I already tried standard and keyword analyzers, but none of them worked exactly how I wanted.

**Edit:** Mainly this Elasticsearch-Query should replace following SQL-Statement (here in Mysql Dialect). @search is the parameter (e.g. "My dog is funny") and column description contain values (e.g. "funny dog" and "cat")

```
select * from pets where lower(@search) like lower(concat('%',description,'%'))
```

Comment: Are these fixed rules?

Comment: Not all completely. "My dog is funny" is fixed ad not found, "My funny dogs" would be ok.